# Social Engine error code 71d17a

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

```
CRIT (2): Error Code: 71d17a  exception 'Zend_Db_Table_Row_Exception' with message 'Specified column "pending" is not in the row' in /home/vpierce/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Db/Table/Row/Abstract.php:201

Stack trace:
#0 /home/vpierce/public_html/application/modules/Sitereview/controllers/IndexController.php(1161): Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract->__set('pending', 0)
#1 /home/vpierce/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action.php(516): Sitereview_IndexController->createAction()
#2 /home/vpierce/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(308): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('createAction')
#3 /home/vpierce/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#4 /home/vpierce/public_html/application/modules/Core/Bootstrap.php(75): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#5 /home/vpierce/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Application.php(160): Core_Bootstrap->run()
#6 /home/vpierce/public_html/application/index.php(205): Engine_Application->run()
#7 /home/vpierce/public_html/index.php(24): include('/home/vpierce/p...')
#8 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Pending" coloumn is missed or empty. Please Check your database or IndexController.php on line 1161.

Answer (score 0):

Check with your table structure  if that column exists